# How to recognize when logon fails in RDP / MSTSC?

Tags: c#, events, rdp, ocx, mstsc

I am working on a C# implementation of RDP / MSTSC using the [MsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/imstscaxevents-onlogonerror).

I need to recognize when the **user logon failed** due to wrong credentials.

The event [OnLogonError](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/termserv/imstscaxevents-onlogonerror) should do the job but it **doesn't fire** (at least not on Server 2016), while the other events seem to work properly.

From the Microsoft documentation of `OnLogonError`:

> LOGON_FAILED_BAD_PASSWORD (0 (0x0))
>
> The logon failed because the logon credentials are not valid.

The behaviour (not fireing OnLogonError) is reported several times, but without solution. The once hint I found is: [at codeproject](https://web1.codeproject.com/Messages/5592119/Re-Csharp-form-AxMsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting-R.aspx):

> After further testing, I found out that if connecting to a Windows 2003 server, the event is entered. But not when connecting to Win7 and newer and Win2008R2 and newer. I wonder if Microsoft removed the event functionality in newer systems?

But from the documentation of the event it should be supported

> Minimum supported client Windows Vista
>
> Minimum supported server Windows Server 2008

---

**Edit**

I downloaded [mRemoteNG](https://github.com/mRemoteNG/mRemoteNG), which seems to be a very clean implementation of RDP. The event is not used there. But when I add it, it also never fires.

**Edit2**

The event seems to work when connecting to a Windows Server 2012 R2. But not for Server 2016 / 2019.

---

**What I tried so far**

- Testing with several implemantations of the class (from MsRdpClient6NotSafeForScripting to MsRdpClient9NotSafeForScripting)
- Testing with several settings

**Questions**

- Is there any setting which could cause this event not to fire?
- Is there any alternative to recognize a logon fail?

Answer (score 1):

Check your ComReference in project file and try setting the WrapperTool to aximp instead of tlbimp. See if AxInterop is generated after the build and test the remote desktop connection again.

It should be looking something like this

```
<COMReference Include="RDPCOMAPILib.dll">
    <Guid>cc802d05-ae07-4c15-b496-db9d22aa0a84</Guid>
    <VersionMajor>1</VersionMajor>
    <VersionMinor>0</VersionMinor>
    <WrapperTool>aximp</WrapperTool>
    <Lcid>0</Lcid>
    <Isolated>false</Isolated>
</COMReference>
```